# Call external webservice from share point 2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, soap

Is it possible, to call external SOAP web service from SharePoint list?

Webservice method should take list item field values as parameters, and then update list item fields by returning values.

Webservice might be call by **list item save event**, or by **clicking added to list item link or button**.

Is it possible at all?

Guide me with proper solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by handling `ItemUpdated` event receiver. In that event you can make the web service call.

Just add web service to the SharePoint Visual Studio Solution. That will create stub/proxy classes. Now you can create web service object and access all the methods.

One thing to keep in mind is that you need to make couple of web configuration changes.